# "New class extends" with a name from variable

Tags: php, class, variables, extends

Is it possible to create a class using a variable instead of its name?

Instead of:

`class weirdclassname extends WP_widget { .... }`

I would like to:

`class $nameVariable extends WP_widget { .... }`

I need it because I create multiple classes and have to invent many different unique names to prevent conflicts. My imagination is already crying =|

Comment: Classes traditionally describe objects. If all your objects are the same then you don't need to create a new class but to create the object. In any case what does a variable store but a name?

Comment: No. If you're trying to do what you're trying to do, you just have your architecture bad.

Comment: It is the reason why there is `namespace` in PHP. To help avoid name conflict.

Comment: |>"you don't need to create a new class" - seems I have to, because Wordpress plugin development rules require it; 
|>"architecture bad" - wordpress, wordpress..
|>"namespace" - yep but wordpress LOVES global variables =|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function [eval](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.eval.php) to define the class dynamically https://implode.io/uP0WXH

```
class Foo
{
}

$child = <<<CLASS
class %s extends Foo
{
    public \$name = '%s';
}
CLASS;

$classNames = ['Class1', 'Class2', 'Class3'];

foreach ($classNames as $className) {
    eval(sprintf($child, $className, $className));
}

print_r(new Class1);

print_r(new Class2);

print_r(new Class3);
```

Comment: I've read about eval and was going to answer "eval? no, thanks, it's a bad realization", but your answer rocks, mate, and looks really decent. Thanks a lot!